# Converting Yearly Data to Daily Using R

Tags: r

I have annual sales data that I would like to make daily. But I am not sure how.
I would like the days to be working days only (excluding weekends) and would repeat the same value for the entire year starting from 1/1/1993

```
dput(dateyear)
structure(c(8735, 9100, 9465, 9831, 10196, 10561, 10926, 11292, 
11657, 12022, 12387, 12753, 13118, 13483, 13848, 14214, 14579, 
14944, 15309, 15675, 16040, 16405), class = "Date")
dput(revenue)
c(97825, 99683, 107893, 116728, 120279, 100697, 160883, 232748, 
213488, 204506, 246738, 298035, 370680, 377635, 404552, 477359, 
310586, 383221, 486429, 482295, 438255, 411939)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. Use `seq` to create a sequence of all days between a start and ending date. This can be done by specifying `by = "days"`.

Step 2. Use `weekdays` to find the days of the week. Then, select those days that are not Saturday or Sunday by using `! %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")`.

Step 3. Create a vector that only contains the years with `format(datedays2, "%Y")`. Use `rle` to find out how many working days there are per year. Select the `lengths` element and use that in `rep` to repeat `revenue` for the number of working days per year.

```
datedays <- seq(as.Date("1993-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by = "days")

datedays2 <- datedays[!weekdays(datedays) %in% c("Saturday","Sunday")]

revenue2 <- rep(revenue, rle(format(datedays2, "%Y"))$lengths)
```